# REDIRCT_URI for a client side only python script using oauth

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, instagram

I would like to use the python instagram api but am struggling over the correct setting for the redirect url.

I have been able to feed the authorize url in by hand into a browser and get a 
token back in the return url. I that case; I set the URI to localhost (127.0.0.1)

Whenever I do this via the api I end up with 400 returns.

What I would really appreciate is 
1) a working example
2) when running  via a script; what should be listening for the server's response that contains the token in its url ?

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: I've done this by setting up a temporary local webserver with flask, getting a free port then specifying that combination in my redirect URL (127.0.0.1:<port>) -- all the webserver needs to do is log the request, it doesn't even really *need* to serve any real page before you can go on doing what you're doing.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. Will give it a try